# Google sheet =getId() script failing for some copied sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this script to return the ID of an open spreadsheet:

```
    function getId() {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
    }
```

In the cell, I've added:

```
    =getId()
```

The problem is, when I copy the spreadsheet, the new spreadsheet returns the ID for the original spreadsheet - not the ID for the active  sheet.

If I enter =getId() in a new cell in the active sheet, it returns the correct ID. So the script is apparently working, it's not just not 'refreshing' the data for a copied sheet.

(Bizarrely, this has worked before! I don't know what's changed but it's stopped returning a new ID value.)

Can anyone suggest how to make sure the ID for the active sheet is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for `function getId()` didn't work for me when calling from a cell using `=getId()`, it's not returning anything at all.

Try this instead:

```
function getId() {
  var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  return id;
}
```

This should return the Spreadsheet ID using the formula, I've tested making a copy of the sheet and it updates as expected.

Comment: Thanks Ross, really appreciate it. Not sure what happened - it had been working with the other code, or seemed to be. I've run your code with a couple of tests and it seems ok. But then it had been working before. I'll keep an eye on it. Thank you!